# vifm: How to set right window to see content of dir or file highlighted in left window

Tags: file-management

How can I set the right window to see the content of the highlighted directory or file in the left window in `vifm`? (like in `ranger`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### For versions prior to 0.8.1 (released on 2016-01-17)

Add command similar to the following one to your `~/.vifm/vifmrc` file as one of the last of `:fileview` commands (because the order in which they appear matters and you don't want it to follow `fileview *`):

```
fileview */ tree %c
```

#### For 0.8.1 and up

Previewing directories is builtin now, just don't redefine viewer for `*/` and it will work (you can use `*[^/]` pattern for `:fileviewer` command to don't match directories).

---

Then turn on quick view with:

```
view
```

You can add this command to your `vifmrc`. Or add `tui` to `'vifminfo'` (e.g. with `set vifminfo+=tui` in `vifmrc`) to make vifm save quick view state between sessions.

### Extra

I also would suggest to add a mapping to switch quick view mode with a key in normal mode to your `~/.vifm/vifmrc` file:

```
nnoremap w :view<cr>
```

### By the way

Sample configuration file of vifm contains commands like these.

> (like in ranger)

If you need closer resemblance, take a look at [`'millerview'`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27millerview%27) and [`'milleroptions'`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27milleroptions%27) options.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not yet allowed to comment, so I provide an answer to get my points.

In addition to xaizek's answer

```
fileview */ tree %c
```

I have added

```
fileview ../ tree %c -L 1
```

below that to be able to see what is in the parent directory while scanning the contents of a directory. This is just for cosmetic completeness. (parent directory is not picked up by */)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can without, possibly, writing your own command.

[`vifm`](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/) is designed as a Midnight Commander like two-pane file explorer. It means that each pane can be considered as a "source" or "target" for your file manipulations. The right pane is pretty much totally disconnected from the left pane and can't be consired a "preview" of the content of some directory on the left pane.

[`ranger`](http://nongnu.org/ranger/index.html) is designed after Mac OS X's Finder's column view where you don't have that notion of "source/target".

I guess it's one style or another. I've got both on all my machines and can't decide which one to throw away as each program has its strong points.

Comment: As long as nobody answers they know how to do it I'll mark this answer as the most suited answer to this question. I also have both installed and I have the same considerations.

Comment: @romainl you are mistaking about vifm. It has `:fileview` and `:view` commands to handle quick view of selected file in the second pane. Different preview programs can be selected with globals. vifm can also be used in one-pane mode with marks and `:pushd/:popd` support. It also has less-like preview mode.

Comment: No, I'm not mistaken about vifm. `:view` only allows to "preview" files while the OP wants to see the content of a directory. I wrote in the 1st line of my answer that he would need to *write is own command* to achieve his goal and you showed him how to write such a command. **One thing I totally failed at (and that I only see right now, as I'm writing this comment) was reading carefully the question: I focused on the "viewing *directories*" part and totally missed the "viewing *files*" part.** I'll be happy to give you the tick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment.

To go a bit further than Svenn comment, you can add to your `.vifmrc`:

```
" Normal dirs
fileview */ tree %c -L <depth>

" Hidden dirs  
fileview *./ tree %c -L <depth>

" .. Parent dir
fileview ../ tree %c -L <depth>
```

Please, note that order has its importance if you want to set a different depth for each kind of folder. Svenn's wildcard doesn't work for hidden directories (`vifm version: 0.9.1` and `tree v1.7.0`.